# Mapping scattered points on a hexagon onto a torus

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, conformal-geometry

Suppose we have a set of scattered points on a regular hexagon centered at the origin and of edge length 1/sqrt(3). I couldn't figure out how I can map these points onto a torus. I have the mapping for a set of points on a unit square, but couldn't do it for the hexagon.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at a tiling of the plane by hexagons. Now connect four neighboring hexagon centers considered as vertices of a parallelogram. The parallelogram with parallel edges identified covers a torus.

Comment: thank you for the great tip @Somos, it worked. Best.